# php variable as conditional assignment

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

I was wondering how can I assign a conditional assignment to a php variable and use it inside other conditional, like this:

```
$cndtnal='&& $x==4'

if($y==5 $cndtnal){
   print 'Hello World';
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @MarcB As long as there's no user-provided input being passed into it, I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use the eval in this line:
    if($y==5 $cndtnal)
like this?
    if($y==5 eval($cndtnal))

Comment: It does make debugging more difficult.

Comment: `if (eval('$y==5'.$cndtnal))`. But it is evil. I urge you find another way to do it.

Comment: You do know that `$x=4` will **always** evaluate to `true` and as such there's no reason to include it in your equality statement, right?

Comment: Hi Andrewsi, i got an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in : eval()'d code on line 1

Answer (score 1):

You should try avoiding the use of **eval** as much as possible, but if you want to use it, then you could do:

```
$cndtnal='&& $x=4';
if($y==5 .eval("return '$cndtnal';")  ){
   echo 'Hello World';
}
else {
    echo "this";
}
```