# Php Variable as conditional assignment with eval()

Tags: php, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php variable as conditional assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170527/php-variable-as-conditional-assignment)

I am trying to concatenate a conditional assignment through php variables like this

```
$cndtnal='&& $x==4';

if($y==5 eval($cndtnal)){
   print 'Hello World';
}
```

But I am getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in : eval()'d code on line 1.

I have tried too :

```
$cndtnal='&& $x==4';

if (eval('$y==5'.$cndtnal)){
       print 'Hello World';
    }
```

But I get the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: [Your last question about this has an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170527/php-variable-as-conditional-assignment) -- does that answer not work?

Comment: Hi rdlowrey, no it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `return` and a semicolon.

But really, you should ***avoid `eval`***.

```
<?php
$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
$test = ' && $bar == 2';
if(eval('return $foo == 1' . $test . ';')) {
    echo "That horribly eval()'d code worked!";
}
?>
```